# How to add bootstrap less css files?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, less, datetimepicker

I'm trying to include a date time picker from [this](http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/demo.php) site and I'm pretty far with the implementation.

The dependancies for this library are 2 less files mentioned on the site too (dropdowns.less and sprites.less). I've installed the bootstrap.less via NuGet package manager which includes those files.

But I got stuck with adding those less files in the header of the _layout page. I simply tried:

```
link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap/less/dropdowns.less")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap/less/sprites.less")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Here is a screenie of how it looks like as soon as you select a date. After selecting a date, you get the option of selecting the time:

[image: messed up]

And this is how it should look like:

[day view](https://raw.github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker/master/screenshot/standard_day.png)

I have also added the javascript files that came along with the bootstrap.less:

```
// Bootstrap 3 script bundle
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundle/scripts/bootstrap_js").Include(
            "~/Content/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-transition.js",
            "~/Content/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-alert.js",
            "~/Content/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-button.js",
            "~/Content/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-carousel.js",
            "~/Content/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-collapse.js",
            "~/Content/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js",
            "~/Content/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-modal.js",
            "~/Content/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js",
            "~/Content/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-popover.js",
            "~/Content/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js",
            "~/Content/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-tab.js",
            "~/Content/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js",
            "~/Content/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-affix.js"));
```

Anyone formiliar with this library that could point me into the right direction for this to work?

**EDIT**
I able to fix the messed up calendar. But now i'm presented with a trail after the datetimepicker is closed. Any idea on how to remove this?

[image: trail]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those .less files just describe the style, not the functionality, you also have to include the

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundle/scripts/bootstrap_js")
```

in your _Layout to pull in the .js files..

~hope that helps

(and you put that bundles.Add(...); in your BundleConfig.cs, right?)

Although, the more that I look at it, it's looking to me like you may have it setup right but that you may have a problem with your date/time data?

Comment: It seems that I forgot the add the css file of it. There were too many bootstrap inclusions which made me overlooked it lol. But there is something else now that bothers me. When the picker closes, it leaves a trail of the borders behind. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Does this happen in all browsers or is it browser specific? (firefox, chrome, safari, etc...)

Comment: This only happens in IE version 10. Just tested it in FF and Chrome. But I don't have safari.

Comment: Maybe IE is going into quirks/compatibility mode.  Check it by bringing up the dev tools with an F12 key press.  If you click on the browser mode, you can change it, then test your page again.  You can try to force it with a <meta> tag (I forget the syntax) to IE10 standards.  It could be that you have an html syntax error in your page or you're writing non-standard html and the other browsers handle it better.  You could try a validator and there are some browser toolbars that I have used in the past too.  Simplest way is a meta to force IE10 standards, if that's the case.